# npm returns module_not_found on react-native-cli install

Tags: node.js, react-native, npm, command-line-interface

I just upgraded my mac pro to Sierra, and now I am trying to install React Native:

```
sudo npm install -g react-native-cli
```

This command fails and I get this message:

```
npm ERR! Darwin 16.6.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "react-native-cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND

npm ERR! Cannot find module 'github-url-from-git'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/gianni/npm-debug.log
```

npm -v: 3.10.10

node -v: v6.11.0

Thanks

Comment: Can you try this https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/9377#issuecomment-257805777

Comment: Thanks @TGMCians, I had to reinstall a few things but it did work.

Comment: What do you mean by "few things"

Comment: well, brew was apparently not linked to node anymore, even though it was installed... so I had to remove it and install it again... after that I could run react-native init command but I had to change permissions using sudo chown -R $USER:$(id -gn $USER) /Users/gianni/.config